# Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "selectedProjectId"

Tags: javascript, webpack, typeerror

Trying to set this variable to an element's id number, but I can't make sense of this error statement.

{Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "selectedProjectId"}

I declared the variable here.

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY = 'project.lists';
const LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY = 'project.selectedProjectId';
const projects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY)) || [];
const selectedProjectId = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY);

function save() {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(projects));
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY, selectedProjectId);
}

export {
    projects,
    save,
    selectedProjectId,
}
```

I try to assign it a different value here.

```
projectList.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
        console.log(e.target.dataset.projectId);
        console.log('works');
        selectedProjectId = e.target.dataset.projectId;
        saveAndRender();
    }
});
```

I'm following webdev simplified's tutorial on a better to-do-list in js. I'm following pretty closely, but mine keeps throwing the type error. How do I fix this? Any advice would be helpful. For more clarification, I am also using webpack if that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` cannot be assigned to a new value. Use `let` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: I tried it. Still throwing the type error. The error is setting getter-only property. It is not assignment to constant variable.

Comment: If where you're assigning it to a different value is in a different file, you can't do that. If you want to edit a value expoerted from a different location, use an object (e.g. `selectedProject = { id: ... }` and then in the other file: `selectedProject.id = ...`

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I had my storage functions in a different module.